# Maximum number of threads of Vulkan compute shader

Tags: gpu, vulkan, compute-shader

How can I use Vulkan to query the maximum number of possible threads/invocations.
And what would happen if I exceeded that number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "maximum number". There are two things you could mean.

1. The maximum total number of invocations that can be executed within any one dispatch call.

   A dispatch call executes some number of work groups, within which execute some number of work items (aka: invocations). The latter is defined within the shader itself with the `local_size_x/y/z` declarations. These are subject to the limitation of `maxComputeWorkGroupInvocations`. That is, the product of `local_size_x/y/z` must be less than or equal to this value.

   However, each of these x/y/z dimensions are themselves subject to limitations, defined by `maxComputeWorkGroupSize`. This is an array of 3 values limiting x/y/z respectively. That is, each dimension cannot exceed the limit defined by that limitation.

   That being said, the product of these limits will be larger than `maxComputeWorkGroupInvocations`, so that's the limitation you should pay attention to.

   A given dispatch call dispatches some number of work groups, which themselves have x/y/z indices. The maximum number along each dimension is defined by the `maxComputeWorkGroupCount` array. There is no singular limit, so the product of each of those array elements defines the maximum number of groups you can dispatch.

   Therefore, the total number of invocations a dispatch call can execute is: `(maxComputeWorkGroupCount[0] * maxComputeWorkGroupCount[1] * maxComputeWorkGroupCount[2]) * maxComputeWorkGroupInvocations`.
2. The maximum number of invocations that can execute simultaneously on a single execution core. This would be useful for optimizing work group sizes and knowing how many invocations could conveniently share data without having excessive synchronization.

   This number cannot technically be queried. However, you can query something that probably represents this number.

   Vulkan 1.1 added the `subgroupSize` property that you can query from a physical device. A "subgroup" is a set of invocations that can inter-communicate with one another. This variable defines the default subgroup size.

   It is *probably* the same as the number of invocations that can execute in lockstep. But it is primarily used for subgroup inter-communication, so if the GPU doesn't offer that as a feature, this will likely be set to 1. Which is *not* the number of invocations that can execute in lockstep on that hardware. So use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

`maxComputeWorkGroupCount` shows the maximum global workgroup size. `maxComputeWorkGroupSize` shows the maximum local workgroup size. `maxComputeWorkGroupInvocations` shows the maximum local workgroup invocations.

If you exceed those numbers, it is undefined behavior.